# Can I send push notification using custom_ids not FCM registration-id from my server?

Tags: firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

If we want to send message to different device we need to specify their `registration_ids` in https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send. Is there some API where we can register users unique `user_id` and send messages using that `user_id`?

My use case is, I am using Parse for notification and if there are 5 people in a chat, we send notification to those 5 people if there is some activity in the chat. We are already storing the `user_id` in our database. Now if there is some API where I can specify the `registration_ids` and `user_id`. And then later just use `user_id` instead of storing `registration_ids` in our database.

Comment: If you want to send a message to everyone in the chat, I'd consider creating a topic for that chat. See my article here: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/08/sending-notifications-between-android.html. Alternatively you could store the FCM-id-to-parse-id mapping in the Firebase Database and do the lookup yourself. But note that either way (unlike with Parse Push) you will need to run code on an app server (something that you control) to handle the *sending* of messages to devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you plan on using FCM for the push notification, short answer is No.

What is required in FCM for you to send to a single or multiple device(s) is/are the registration token(s) and by using the corresponding parameters `to`, `registration_ids` in the payload to send it to them.

Other details is pretty much covered by @FrankvanPuffelen's comment.